# (Django/Python) How to limit onetoonefield's choices?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, admin

I'm using a poorman's method to provide translated content. For this I've added translation fields for each language in the model.

These field's are onetoone field's since for each content there can be only one translation per language.

How could I limit the choices of these fields in the admin? The point is to provide content (model instances) with lang attribute set to ceartain language i.e. en for translations_en field.

Django documentation doesn't state onetoonefield at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to overwrite the `ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)` method as described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey)?

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "translation":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Translation.objects.filter(lang="en")
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: No, since I didn't see foreignkey and onetoone as the same. Are they the same or should I change from onetoone to foreingkey?

Comment: Great @user1271930! This seemed to do the job. I just changed from onetoonefield to foreignkey and defined formfield_for_foreignkey in admin.py and that's it :)